# Show that $n$ is prime.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $x$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i$ is a prime number

Thus, show that $n$ is also prime

Comment: I have voted to close because, as your question stands, it is just the statement of a problem. You should edit it in to give some background on what you've tried. This helps and to know where you actually need help, and also stops us doing people's assessed homework for them...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind the next time, I understood how to approach this problem now.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you had by your comments to the answer :-)

Comment: @AdityaParson Ignore those people asking you to show what you have tried. You add that if you like. Either way you are going to get an answer if there is an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Two cases:

**If $x>1$**

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$

If $n$ is not a prime, then $n=pq$ with $p, q>1$, thus $x^n-1=(x^p)^q-1$ is divisible by $x^p-1$ (see below [1]), which is greater than $1$, and greater than $x-1$, hence $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ has some divisor, and is not a prime. Contradiction, so $n$ is indeed a prime.

**If $x=1$**

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i=n$$

So it's immediate that $n$ is a prime.

---

[1]
$$\frac{(x^p)^q-1}{x^p-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{q-1} x^p$$

and the sum is an integer, so the quotient is exact, and $x^p-1$ divides $(x^p)^q-1$.

Comment: Why did you proceed using $x=1$?

Comment: Two cases, first $x>1$, then $x=1$. The sum is different, so the argument is not the same either.

Comment: I didn't read correctly. My bad